# Disabling the title of a QGroupBox

Tags: qt

Given a QGroupBox, calling its member function, "setEnabled(false)" will grey out and disable its contents.

However, how do I grey out the title of the box?  Presumably there's some workaround involving styles that I could use if there isn't a simple method somewhere.  If so, what is the easiest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to set is the `color` property of the `title` sub-control:

```
groupBox->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox::title{ color: gray }")
```

**EDIT**

You could also achieve the same effect using `QPalette`, without the use of stylesheets

```
// Create a palette
QPalette palette;
palette.setColor(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::WindowText,
                 QApplication::palette().color(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::WindowText));
groupBox->setPalette(palette);
```

Comment: This answers my (poorly worded) question.  

However, I had actually meant "grey out" as in, "make the same color as the text in other widgets (QLabel, for example) when they are disabled".

My full solution is:

    QPalette palette = QApplication::palette();
    QColor color = palette.color(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Text);

    groupBox->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox::title{ color: " + color.name() + " }");`

Comment: Check my updated answer for a better approach using palettes and without the use of stylesheets